# Blit faster than conditional + pointer increment?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, memcpy, blit

This is my simple blitting function:

```
static void blit8(unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src)
{
    byte i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (*src != 0) {
            *dest = *src;
        }
        ++dest;
        ++src;
    }
}
```

I'm already at `-O3`, and `blit8` being inlined. `restrict` (gcc) has no effect here. Nor does incrementing the pointers in any different way, or using another number as transparency, or another type for `i`... I even tried passing a 1-byte bitmask and checking that instead of dereferencing `src`. Increasing the limit of `i` to, say, 16 seems to provide a *very* minor speedup (~4-6%), but I'm working with 8-byte, not 16-byte chunks.

My bottleneck? No clue actually, I don't think it's the cache line since, my miss rate is low(?) and `64` (my cacheline size) has no special significance when changing things around. But I don't think it's memory speed either (since `memcpy` is faster, more on that in a bit).

`cg_annotate` says this about `blit8` (without inlining):

```
Ir    I1mr   ILmr            Dr      D1mr   DLmr          Dw       D1mw    DLmw  file:function
3,747,585,536      62      1 1,252,173,824 2,097,653      0 674,067,968          0       0  ppu.c:blit8.constprop.0
```

Regular `cachegrind` output (with inlining):

```
I   refs:      6,446,979,546
I1  misses:          184,752
LLi misses:           22,549
I1  miss rate:          0.00%
LLi miss rate:          0.00%

D   refs:      2,150,502,425  (1,497,875,135 rd   + 652,627,290 wr)
D1  misses:       17,121,968  (    2,761,307 rd   +  14,360,661 wr)
LLd misses:          253,685  (       70,802 rd   +     182,883 wr)
D1  miss rate:           0.8% (          0.2%     +         2.2%  )
LLd miss rate:           0.0% (          0.0%     +         0.0%  )

LL refs:          17,306,720  (    2,946,059 rd   +  14,360,661 wr)
LL misses:           276,234  (       93,351 rd   +     182,883 wr)
LL miss rate:            0.0% (          0.0%     +         0.0%  )
```

`0.8%` D1 miss rate? Sounds quite low to me.

The most interesting thing to me though, is that removing the `0`-check (becoming functionally identical to `memcpy`) provides a <1% speedup, even though:

`memcpy` is ~25% faster. I want as close to the speed of raw `memcpy` as I can get, while preserving color `0` as transparent.

The problem is, as far as I know, no vector instructions support conditionals, but I need to to preserve `dest` where `src` is `0`. Is there anything [fast] that can act like `OR` but on a byte level?

I read before there was an extension or something to tell the CPU to not cache some data, but I can't find it again. My idea is to not directly read from `src`, only write from it to `dest`, and make sure it's not be cached. Then just read from a bitmask to check for transparency. *I just don't know how to actually do that.* Is that even possible let alone fast? I don't know that either, hence why I'm asking this question.

I would prefer a tips on how to make faster with just C, maybe some gcc extensions, but if x86 assembly is the only way, so be it. Helping me understand my *actual* bottleneck (since I'm confused by my results) would help too.

Comment: Why not use memcpy? It is super optimized and it get replaced by some low-level assembly operation if available on your architecture.

Comment: @sturcotte06 This code doesn't overwrite with zeros, so not the same as memcpy.

Comment: @sturcotte06 OP already mentioned `memcpy`.

Comment: Then I don't think you can match memcpy performance, since you can't take advantage of a x86 instruction.

Comment: As in, there is *no way whatsoever* to blit faster?

Comment: It can be done with SIMD instructions, depending on which CPUs you're targeting.  Though it will probably help more with 16 bytes than with 8.

Comment: Are there SIMD instructions which allow masking or conditionals though? That's my problem. I could use SIMD but it doesn't seem to be compatible with  masking.

Comment: Of course there are.

Comment: It's very compatible with masking. See for example the `pblendvb` instruction which seems to fit here.

Comment: i didn't see that when i was looking at SIMD instructions before (since there were so many) i'll try that and see how it helps

Comment: Have a look at this page that makes it easy to search for SIMD instructions: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mentioned if you use GCC or not but let's assume yes.
GCC is picky if it comes to conditions inside loops - that is why your example fails to vectorize.

So this code:

```
void blit8(unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src)
{
    char i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (*src != 0) {
            *dest = *src;
        }
        ++dest;
        ++src;
    }
}
```

ends up as:

```
blit8:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi]
        test    al, al
        je      .L5
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], al
.L5:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi+1]
        test    al, al
        je      .L6
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+1], al
.L6:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi+2]
        test    al, al
        je      .L7
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+2], al
.L7:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi+3]
        test    al, al
        je      .L8
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+3], al
.L8:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi+4]
        test    al, al
        je      .L9
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+4], al
.L9:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi+5]
        test    al, al
        je      .L10
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+5], al
.L10:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi+6]
        test    al, al
        je      .L11
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+6], al
.L11:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi+7]
        test    al, al
        je      .L37
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+7], al
.L37:
        ret
```

It was unrolled by compiler but still it works on single bytes.

But there is one trick that works pretty often in such cases - instead of if(cond) use ternary operator. This will fix one problem.
But there is another one - GCC refuses to vectorize short small block - 8 bytes in this example. So let's use another trick - do computation on bigger block but ignore part of it.

Here is my example:

```
void blit8(unsigned char* dest, unsigned char* src)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char temp_dest[16];
    unsigned char temp_src[16];

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) temp_dest[i] = dest[i];
    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) temp_src[i] = src[i];

    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) 
    {
        temp_dest[i] = (temp_src[i] != 0) ? temp_src[i] : temp_dest[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) dest[i] = temp_dest[i];
}
```

and corresponding assembly:

```
blit8:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        vpxor   xmm0, xmm0, xmm0
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-40], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-24], rax
        vmovdqa xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        vpcmpeqb        xmm0, xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-24]
        vpblendvb       xmm0, xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rsp-40], xmm0
        vmovq   QWORD PTR [rdi], xmm0
        ret
```

NOTE:
I didn't benchmarked it - it is just prove SIMD code could be generated by using proper coding rules and tricks ;)

Comment: With this amount of obscure mangling to make the compiler happy it's probably better (less fragility, easier to maintain) to use intrinsics instead.

Comment: If he would use 16 bytes instead of 8 then it would require just replacing if() with ? :. When using intrinsics manually this step also have to be done (8->16) and as you can see this conversion if cheap. And no - intrinsics are not easier to maintain not to mention code is not portable anymore. Autovectorizer works well - one just need to follow restrictions listed in documentation.

Comment: You mean, for the current version of one specific compiler on one specific architecture with one specific set of args, auto-vectorisation happens to work badly (no prefetch, no cache line flush) if and only if you mangle the code to suit that one version of one specific compiler on one specific architecture with one specific set of args?

Comment: If you call most popular compiler "specific", by "current" any version several years old, by "mangling" and "specific args" following autovectorization rules than I have no more questions.

Answer (score 1):

If your compiler/architecture supports [vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) (like clang and gcc) you can use something like:

```
//This may compile to awful code on x86_64 b/c mmx is slow (its fine on arm64)
void blit8(void* dest, void* src){
typedef __UINT8_TYPE__ u8x8  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (8), __may_alias__));
    u8x8 *dp = dest, d = *dp, *sp = src, s = *sp, cmp;
    cmp = s == (u8x8){0};
    d &= cmp;
    *dp = s|d;
}

//This may compile to better code on x86_64 - worse on arm64
void blit8v(void* dest, void* src){
typedef __UINT8_TYPE__ u8x16  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
typedef __UINT64_TYPE__ u64, u64x2  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
    u8x16 *dp = dest, d = *dp, *sp = src, s = *sp, cmp;
    cmp = s == (u8x16){0};
    d &= cmp;
    d |= s;
    *(u64*)dest = ((u64x2)d)[0];
}

//This one is fine on both arm and x86, but 16 bytes vs. 8
void blit16(void* dest, void* src){
typedef __UINT8_TYPE__ u8x16  __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (16), __may_alias__));
    u8x16 *dp = dest, *sp = src, d = *dp, s = *sp, cmp;
    cmp = s == (u8x16){0};
    *dp = s|(d & cmp);
}
```

Compiles on arm to:

```
blit8:
        ldr     d1, [x1]
        ldr     d2, [x0]
        cmeq    v0.8b, v1.8b, #0
        and     v0.8b, v0.8b, v2.8b
        orr     v0.8b, v0.8b, v1.8b
        str     d0, [x0]
        ret
blit16:
        ldr     q1, [x1]
        ldr     q2, [x0]
        cmeq    v0.16b, v1.16b, #0
        and     v0.16b, v0.16b, v2.16b
        orr     v0.16b, v0.16b, v1.16b
        str     q0, [x0]
        ret
```

on x86_64:

```
blit8v:                                 # @blit8v
        movdqa  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
        pxor    xmm1, xmm1
        pcmpeqb xmm1, xmm0
        pand    xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdi]
        por     xmm1, xmm0
        movq    qword ptr [rdi], xmm1
        ret
blit16:                                 # @blit16
        movdqa  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
        pxor    xmm1, xmm1
        pcmpeqb xmm1, xmm0
        pand    xmm1, xmmword ptr [rdi]
        por     xmm1, xmm0
        movdqa  xmmword ptr [rdi], xmm1
        ret
```